# Can't Save Edit with Code Snippet

Tags: support

I'm trying to edit my original question: [Deserialize SOAP to DTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57066725/deserialize-soap-in-file-to-dto)
Mainly, I'm trying to add my test method per request from dbc.

I click the {} button in the editor, then paste my code, but when I try to save my edit, I get "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code." This despite simply cutting from VS and pasting over the "enter code here". In the preview, however, the code renders just as I expect, grey box with syntax highlighting.

How do I solve this problem.

Comment: What code you trying to insert? How can we tell if it is well format or no if we cannot see it?

Comment: Try to first paste your code, then select it and _then_ hit the `{}` button.

Comment: How do I show you the C# code if I can't save it?

Comment: I've tried it both ways. Pasting my code first, then highlighting makes it worse than it was. I'm going to try adding the snippet to this message just to see what happens.

Comment: If you can't add the code here, try taking a screenshot of your attempt to add it.

Comment: a code-snippet is not the proper element for displaying a SOAP response, since it will never run (opposite to HTML + JS). I usually just paste, then select the code and hit `Control` + `K`... a code block and a code snippet are not the same.

Comment: edited the question and converted the code snippet into a code block; it had lang HTML. for C# that would be `<!-- language: c# -->`. it's based upon [code-prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify).

Comment: Sorry Ivar & Co. I read that email and tried to follow the information. It didn't fix the problem

Comment: The SOAP message was saved using the <> button at the top of the editor. Also, if you look at the original message, you'll see that I was able to format individual lines of code using the {} button. It's only the actual test method, 9 lines counting the signature and braces that claim to be improperly formatted and won't let e save.

Comment: One other thing, as I mentioned in this OP, looking at the message preview below the text editor, the code block displayed just fine. I just couldn't save the edit.

Comment: You can select the code and press `CTRL+K` to properly format (there is also a button like this `<>` which does the same work). Or you can format the code like this: ``` (optionally you can add the language name here) Code ```. Also you can convert the code into a snippet by adding this line before your code: `<!-- language: c -->`, here c for c language. Simply replace it with other language name when you need.